# How can I make fences show up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a long section of fences on a road near my base. The problem is that a good portion of these fences aren't showing up. (Note the torch next to the fence which should fix the glitch)

[image: Invisible Woman! Where?]

So how can I fix this? I've tried changing render distance (fog), reloading, etc.

Comment: I had this problem once as well. I think you can just delete one of the fences and replace it.

Comment: @Kevin: Nope, that didn't work. It might be because this is a **really** long section of fence (at least 500 meters).

Comment: Hmm. [The Minecraft Wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Fence#Glitches) notes that you can place a normal block next to the fences and they should reappear. However, if you remove that block the fences will disappear again, so perhaps you could work that into your design?

Comment: @Kevin: I tried that with dirt and cobblestone. The fences still didn't reappear.

Comment: Well than I have no idea. What happens if you destroy the invisible fence closest to the line of visible fences, and then put it back; does it become invisible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This glitch is not because of lighting and fogs problem, it's similar to the dark areas glitch. So the only solution i found is placing a block near the fence, and the fence show up, !IMPORTANT! only if you place the block from west or south to the fence it will work so you probably tried the wrong direction try all four and it will work! like that:

before:
[image]
after:
[image]
BUT if you remove the block the fence become invisible again.
so just place one block near each row are invisible fence.

Comment: Do you have a link about the dark areas glitch? I've never heard about it, and would like to know more.

Comment: its when a piece of land turns black untill you place or remove a block in the area. here is some video in youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mjf56mV4y4s

Comment: Well that worked. Also that is extremely weird.

Comment: btw if you lead the fence row to a hidden place and put the block there and after that clear the extra fence, the rest of the row will still be visible as long as this "hidden" block is not removed. this is even more weird XD

Comment: @Vlad: Does that underwater ladder off in the distance go down to your base?

Comment: yes! :)
it's indestructible be creepers and "very close" to the mine!

Answer (score 8):

[According to Notch](http://notch.tumblr.com/post/5775170768/the-changelist-for-1-6), this glitch will be fixed in 1.6:

> - Fixed fences and stairs sometimes becoming invisible

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I fixed this issue by breaking up my very long fence (along a road between two very distant houses; don't know how far in terms of blocks/meters, but it was about 1/2 to 2/3 of a day to walk between them) into shorter sections by putting a stone block in, which also conveniently gave me an attractive place to put a torch to light my way and make my road somewhat safe to travel even at night.

So instead of

> FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF [ad nauseum]

I had

> FFFFFFFFSFFFFFFFFSFFFFFFFFSFFFFFFFF [etc]

(F = Fence; S = Stone)

Sorry for the lack of a screenshot, but that world has long since been lost. :-(

Comment: Another fix is to build "[streetlights](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Fence#Glitches)" on top of the fence.

Comment: @Seven: I actually went with the streetlight method. It not only fixes the glitch, but also looks nice.